# What word/phrase can I use for "Arson card?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Many years ago at a corporate training event we were playing a simulation game where each team had an "arson card" they could play during their turn. It doesn't take much imagination to understand what this card does: it turns the game into a scorched-earth strategy where the intent is to destroy the other team.

What work or phrase can I use to represent this idea? Something like, "if they don't agree to term x, we can take action y as our arson card."

Answer (score 4):

*Nuclear option:*

> 2 : an extreme option regarded as a drastic step or last resort [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuclear%20option)

The definition doesn't state the rather obvious connotation of violence, or the scorched earth that you mention, but the destructiveness is inherent to the meaning.